# Outlook 2011 Mac can't connect after Service Pack 2 installation on Exchange Server 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook, mac, connection

After the installation of Service Pack 2 on Exchange Server 2007, all Mac Outlook 2011 clients can't connect to the server. All other clients (Windows Outlook 2007, iPhone, ...) don't have problems connecting.

The Mac Outlook 2011 clients are manually configured with the server's adress using SSL access. The connection's certificate is self-signed. That was never a problem though. The Macs haven't joined the AD domain.

I enabled logging on the client. It only shows some issues with Exchange's Autodiscovery feature which isn't configured on the server. It seems that Outlook 2011 doesn't even try to connect. At least there is no sign in the error log.

There are no hints in the server's event log either.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to review this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2264110.

While it relates to BIS, I've seen others reference it as a fix for the Outlook 2011 issue i.e. it's the same underlying cause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue was resolved tonight with the installation of Service Pack 3 for Exchange Server 2007

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **Service Pack 3** for Exchange Server 2007 solved the problem. All clients can connect now.